# PHP / SQL Query dynamic record from url

Tags: php

I currently have this:

```
<?php
  $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'dev');
  if(!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("myDB");
  $query = "SELECT * FROM pages where id=1";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  $contents = $row['content'];
  echo $contents;
?>
```

See this part: `SELECT * FROM pages where id=1`

1 is the record id and it's currently hardcoded. What I need to do is change it so it get's the record id from the url...for example: mysite.com/index.php?2 would show record id 2 ...

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn that hardcoded value into a variable.

```
<?php
    //assumes you have a querystring like: http://mysite.com/index.php?id=3
    $id = $_GET['id'];


  $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'dev');
  if(!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("myDB");


    //Make your variable safe for use with mysql
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM pages where id=" . $id;
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  $contents = $row['content'];
  echo $contents;
?>
```

Comment: You should explain how to make the URL look like that programatically.

Answer (score 2):

let say the url is something like that: mysite.com/index.php?id=2

in your index.php:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
// your sanitizing methods for id to avoid SQL injection

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'dev');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("diy");
$query = "SELECT * FROM pages where id = ".$id;
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$contents = $row['content'];
echo $contents;
?>
```

Beware of [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: You should explain *why* the URL looks like that.

Answer (score 1):

Basic example using `mysite.com/index.php?id=x` as your URLs where x is the Id:

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];

$query = sprintf("
    SELECT * 
    FROM pages 
    WHERE id = %d",
    mysql_real_escape_string($id)
);
```

With your connection lines included of course, you should also validate.

Answer (score 1):

URL data is interpreted using the GET method. First, you should [look here for how to use it](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_FORM_METHOD_GET.html), and [here for how to read it](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp).

Basically, your URL will look like this:

```
mysite.com/index.php?id=2
```

Then, you could read in the URL variable like this:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

`mysql_real_escape_string()` will help avoid SQL injection, but requires an existing connection, so your code would look like this:

```
<?php
  // Set up connection

  $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM pages where id = '.$id;

  // Run the query
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to extract it from the URL.

```
$retval=preg_match( "@(\d+)$@", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $match );
$index=-1;
if( $retval ) { 
    $index = $match[1];
}
```

This approach allows you to continue using the URL scheme you described in the question without prepending id=.  Whether that's a good idea or not is probably debateable.

Comment: Why not use GET or POST data?

Comment: I answered the question that was asked, which did not include a variable identifier.

Answer (score -1):

http://pastebin.com/NEZe7jjL

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test', 'user', 'password', array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'set names utf8',
));

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE `id` = :page');
$stmt->bindValue(':page', $_GET['page'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
```

yoursite.com/index.php?page=2